# Is new line a separator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, knockout.js, google-chrome-devtools, knockout-2.0

While debugging a web SPA issue, I stumbled on something to which I could not find concrete references online: missing comma separator between function expressions in javascript. Here's the details:

This works - explicit comma as a separator is there (note - intentionally on one line):

`var f1 = function() { console.log(1); }, f2 = function() { console.log(2);}`

This however doesn't seem to work, trying it in the Chrome console (again - one-liner on purpose):

```
var f5 = function() { console.log(5); } f6 = function() { console.log(6);} 
VM37860:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Then this one seems to work - notice missing comma:

```
> var f3 = function() { 
   console.log(3); 
  } 
  f4 = function() { 
   console.log(4);
  }
< function f4()
> f4()
  4
< undefined
> f3()
  3
< undefined
```

I am looking for explanation or a reference to one as to why multi-line but missing comma seems to work.

The ramification was that a missing comma in our source that slipped into the build caused unexpected behavior in otherwise syntax-correct script bundle (the script snippet containing the missing comma piece is bundled together with many other components on the server side and emitted as a single script tag to the browser). I.e. Chrome and FF were not reporting syntax errors, yet script behavior was incorrect (it's a complex knockout.js-based SPA but it seemed as if the wrong function out of many functions with same name, but different scope, was being called; version of knockout used is 2.x).

Regardless - I am interested if someone can explain the console behavior from pure Javascript / Chrome console point of view, outside of the scope of knockout-based SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript will assume semicolons at some line breaks. Ugh. So your second variable was a global, not part of the `var`. http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Comment: why! whyyyy! whyyyyyyyyy! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use comma, it means "a sentence" at same line. In another line Javascript will assume another sentence. And comma can be used "a lot of variable".

for example,  `var f1, f2`--> `var f1; var f2;`
var f3 = 10
f4 = 20 // it is global variable. it is not same line.`